# Statsmodels import problems

Tags: python, python-venv, python-packaging

I'm having trouble importing statsmodels into my Jupyter Notebook where I'm running Python 3.8.3

My error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'`

Things I've tried:

```
pip install statsmodels
conda install statsmodels
pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels
```

This is all done in my virtual environment, which is activated in the jupyter notebook I'm attempting the import in.
I've also attempted importing using `import statsmodels.api as sm`, `import statsmodels.robust as rb` as I saw some SO posts suggesting it, but I still get the same error.
When I type !conda list on my terminal, I see statsmodels in the available packages, yet I still can't import it.
Running out of ideas here, any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you check it using interactive python? if it's installed properly.

Comment: Maybe you have both python version installed and you are running notebook on python 2. Try with !python --version

Comment: When I run !python --version I get Python 3.8.3

I tried running scripts outside of jupyter notebook and got no errors. It looks like there's something wrong with the way my anaconda distribution was installed? Not sure how to fix...